# How to pass a method as callback

Tags: callback, rust

In Python or C++, a class say A can delegate some work to another instance of class Say B, and set a callback method of A in B.
I try to do this in Rust, but so far I got nowhere, beaten by Rust compiler.

Here is Code I have tried, remaining code is at the end of this post.

In A::test I tried using closure to get a Fn() trait object as callback.

```
// let b = B::new(self.finish)); // ideally but would not compile

// let test :Box<Fn(String)> = Box::new(move |msg| {self.finish(msg);}); // cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
// let b = B::new(&test);

// let b = B::new(&Box::new( |msg| {A::finish(&self, msg);} )); // expected trait std::ops::Fn, found closure
// let b = B::new(&Box::new( |msg| {self.finish(msg);} )); // expected trait std::ops::Fn, found closure
```

Nothing work yet. Is there a way doing this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Or Am I fundamentally wrong? Do Rust request an other way to implement the idea here?

Here is my testing code

[Play Ground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=496829a5ae65eca989fdaa3c0c9dd1db)

```
struct A {}

impl A {
    fn finish(&self, msg: String) {
        println!("{}", msg);
    }

    fn test(&self) {

        //let b = B::new(self.finish)); // would not compile

        // let test :Box<Fn(String)> = Box::new(move |msg| {self.finish(msg);}); // cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
        // let b = B::new(&test);

        // let b = B::new(&Box::new( |msg| {A::finish(&self, msg);} )); // expected trait std::ops::Fn, found closure
        let b = B::new(&Box::new( |msg| {self.finish(msg);} )); // expected trait std::ops::Fn, found closure

        b.start("hi".to_string().clone());
    }
}

struct B<'b> {
    // cb:fn(msg:String),
    cb: &'b Box<Fn(String)>,
}

impl<'b> B<'b> {
    fn new(cb: &'b Box<Fn(String)>) -> B<'b> {
        B { cb: cb }
    }

    fn start(&self, msg: String) {
        (self.cb)(msg);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A {};
    a.test();
}
```

Comment: Why is all the code commented out? Please don't do that! Also, please use `rustfmt` in the upper right corner of the playground or by using `cargo fmt` on your machine.

Comment: @hellow Thanks for the advise. I am new to Rust, didn't know that. The Play Ground is Brilliant Idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can pass a method as callback to your struct and call it from this struct's method. And you don't need to box the closure as you pass a reference:

```rust
struct A {}

impl A {
    fn finish(&self, msg: String) {
        println!("{}", msg);
    }

    fn test(&self) {
        let fun = |msg: String| self.finish(msg);
        let b = B::new(&fun);
        b.start("hi".to_string().clone());
    }
}

struct B<'b> {
    cb: &'b Fn(String),
}

impl<'b> B<'b> {
    fn new(cb: &'b Fn(String)) -> B<'b> {
        B { cb }
    }

    fn start(&self, msg: String) {
        (self.cb)(msg);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A {};
    a.test();
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0c06b78763dcb75e377da60df8f88c59)

The box is useful when you move your function to the new struct, which is not your case.

**Note:** As your function is called `start`, I suspect in your real use case you want to start a thread, in which case you should probably look at [channels](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.7.2/crossbeam/channel/index.html) instead of callbacks.

Comment: Thanks, can you please give more insight about the usage of Box<Fn()>.

Comment: @Ian.Zhang A Box is useful to store non Sized values. A `Fn(String)` struct parameter doesn't have a size known at compile time, which is why you need to box it. If you store a reference, there's no need for it: references have a constant size.

Comment: Yes, originally I started a thread and tried using callback gather results, but failed. Then solve that using channels. I wander if callback would work too.

Comment: The easy and clean solution is to use channels rather than try to pass your callbacks to other threads.

Comment: I See, Thanks again